# jQuery Datepicker() on a ASPX page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datepicker

Completely confused as to why this isn't working...  The error I receive is:

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'

**Master.master**

```
<head id="head1" runat="server">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#ctl00_cphMain_txtExpDate").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

**Page.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpDate" runat="server" Visible="true" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

When the page loads, I immediately get the JavaScript error.  But when I view source, everything looks fine:

**View Source, from browser**

```
<input name="ctl00$cphMain$txtExpDate" type="text" id="ctl00_cphMain_txtExpDate" />
```

It runs without error in JSFiddle and even shows the picker popup.  What is causing the error?  This is a C# ASP.NET web application.

**JSFiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/ncojuu21/

Comment: _JavaScript error_...that could be from other js codes.

Comment: i guess you need to remove this  `runat="server"` from the head.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV it's an asp:TextBox which is rendered as a regular HTML input type at page load.

Comment: @Jai I can't do without the runat="server" in the Head as it's needed to use the Title tag, which is required.

Comment: Ok got it ... thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused my MasterPage having duplicate jQuery references.  Issue was resolved when one reference was removed and now the .datepicker() is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the script with `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script type="javascript">`.
Replace `$("#ctl00_cphMain_txtExpDate")` by `$("#<%=txtExpDate.ClientID%>")`

Comment: Solution looks good however I can't use txtExpDate.ClientID because my application uses a MasterPage and the script is in the Head of this MasterPage.  The control, txtExpDate, resides in another ASPX page which is contained in the MasterPage...

Comment: What about using a specific Css class as a selector instead of the control ID??

Comment: Perhaps, but shouldn't it work without the CSS selector?  I think the attempt in the first post is more simplified than a CSS selector.  I could be wrong, however.  Can you please provide an example?

Comment: `$(".echancier-date").datepicker({ changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onClose: function (selectedDate)
    {
        $(this).parent().find('.echancier-date').datepicker("option", "defaultDate", selectedDate)
    }
});`

and my textbox is bellow:
`<asp:TextBox Id="EchancierdateID" runat="server" CssClass="echancier-date"/>`

Comment: Tried using your example function and gave the asp:TextBox your CssClass but the error is still the same.

Comment: And your browser cash is it clean?

Comment: Yea, cleaned the solution, rebuilt and cleared my browsers cache. Same problem